# Скрипт для копирования

Tags: windows, cmd

Пише вот такой скрипт на копирование файлов из OneDrive папки локально на винт, но выдает ошибку

> Invalid number of parameters

```
xcopy C:\Users\%UserName%\OneDrive\Temp C:\Temp /E /C /Y /V
```

Comment: Зря вы считаете что профили пользователя всегда находятся в папке `C:\Users` и имя папки с профилем совпадает с именем пользователя. Лучше используйте переменную среды `%UserProfile%`

Comment: спасибо за информацию, буду знать на будующее

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По всей видимости, у вас в имени пользователя используются пробелы, попробуйте взять пути в кавычки:

```
xcopy "C:\Users\%UserName%\OneDrive\Temp" "C:\Temp" /E /C /Y /V
```

Также можно попробовать получить альтернативное имя директории командой

```
dir /X ~1 c:\Users
```

и подставить его. Например, вместо `Program Files`, `PROGRA~1`.

Comment: тот же результат что без кавычек

Comment: Можно попробовать выполнить команду `dir /X ~1 c:\Users`, чтобы посмотреть альтернативное имя директории и подставить его. Например, вместо `Program Files`, `PROGRA~1`.

Comment: попробовал, но не помогло((

Comment: @Elanyl так все-таки, помогло или нет? Почему одновременно присутствуют ваши комментарии что не помогло, и зеленая галочка, которой отмечаются ответы которые помогли?

Comment: @PavelMayorov нашел лишний пробел в команде как и указано в ответе)